# Aligning input fields for my web page in react js. Cant seem to get an idea of the alignment that i must follow. Layout attached

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

[image]

This is a rough layout for the webpage to be designed.

Comment: You can try to use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap. Just follow the instructions. It's pretty straightforward.
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/

```html
<Row>
  <Col sm={3}>
    // left container
  </Col>
  <Col sm={9}>
    // right container
    <Row>
      <Col sm={4}></Col>
      <Col sm={4}></Col>
      <Col sm={4}></Col>
    </Row>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: Thank you so much but how to align those Upload image boxes though

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you go through the link you would find that viewport consists of 12 units. So you just need to follow this.
Now you can create your left container from 3 units by adding a class "col-sm-3" and your right container from 9 units by adding class "col-sm-9"
Now again divide your right container into pieces